# tuber: connect R with Youtube API

Tags: r, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm following the steps from this documentation to access Youtube API from R: [Google Developers API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) and [Github](https://github.com/soodoku/tuber).

I want to create a shiny app with R to analyse Youtube data: *channel subscribers, views, comments ....*

The steps I follow:

1. I create the project on Google Cloud (Web application) with my Google account.
2. I enable Youtube API data.
3. Installing and loading `tuber` package in R.
4. I write this code: `> yt_oauth("app_id", "app_password")`. I show below where I take these two fields.
   [image]
5. For getting video stats in R: `> get_stats(video_id="Im69kzhpR3I")`

So I get the following error:

### Error: HTTP failure: 403

Comment: Have you completed the other two fields below Restricciones? You might need to complete the URI at the very least (you could try using the value `http://localhost:1410`.) Apart from that, I feel like you have missed out some steps. Are you acquiring an access token?

Comment: And from this link, did you also enable Freebase API? https://github.com/soodoku/tuber