# Connecting R to YouTube with "Tuber" - Unable to read token error

Tags: r, oauth, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am receiving an error when attempting to open an OAuth connection from R to YouTube so as to collect analytics on a channel

There are similar questions on the site already but with different errors and consulting them already I'm unable to determine the problem.

As this guide directs https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuber/vignettes/tuber-ex.html I setup the application and got the ID and secret, similar to this user (I also have not completed any boxes for URLs, as I am not trying to create any sort of public application, simply a connection to go into a YT channel:

[tuber: connect R with Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437412/tuber-connect-r-with-youtube-api)

I have also enabled all of the YouTube APIs as directed.  WHen I run the required code for OAuth:

```
yt_oauth("App_ID", 
         "App_Secret")
```

I got the following:

```
Error in yt_oauth("App_ID",  : 
  Unable to read token from:.httr-oauth
```

I have tried a number of other options based on other answers however to find the root of the problem, I have just posted the first error I am receiving.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the token parameter as empty.

```
yt_oauth(app_id = "your_app_id", 
         app_secret = "your_app_secret", 
         token = "")
```